# Memory error using beautiful soup to parse ~100mb html file with python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm getting a memory error when I run the code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open(r'C:\user\table.html', 'r') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
    found = soup.find("td", text = "A")
    print(found)
f.closed
```

This code will work on small html files. However, when I run it with my ~100mb html table it will slowly eat up memory until the program crashes. Task manager shows python.exe taking up 2gb of memory when the program crashes. I've tried looking through the beautifulsoup documentation, but I cannot figure out why this program is taking up 20x more memory than the size of my html file.

Comment: possibly helpful article: http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2014/09/why-does-my-100mb-file-take-2gb-of.html

Comment: Why would anyone make a 100mb HTML table in the first place? Just curious.

Comment: The data was output as an html file. I could have it output as a csv text file but I think I would be in the same scenario.

Comment: You can use pandas to read data from CSV. Read the data as chunks using `chunksize`

Comment: You could possibly reduce memory requirements by using a [SoupStrainer](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document). Could you add [edit] the question and include the table with a few rows of HTML ?

Comment: Thanks for the article @davedwards. I used excel to convert the html file to csv. Then I used python's csv library to parse the file.